# Library to mimic ctrl+f search functionality

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, winjs

I am trying to implement <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> functionality within an html webpage. I can not use the browser's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> functionality, because the page is not running in a standard browser - it is running instead as an html5 app on Win8.

I would like a library that will mimic most of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> functionality, such as highlighting found matches, moving to the next, etc. I did some searching but was not able to find one, and figured I'd ask.

Comment: Do you mean you need a text search on your application page?

Comment: yes, kind of. More-so I'd also like the UI that would be needed with search as well.

Comment: have you tried using the window.find() function?